# 80s (or earlier) YA book: orphan, misfit boy discovers a Pygmy village, gets stabbed by a venomous rattlesnake fang in a trap

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a YA fiction book about a boy who discovers an ancient archeological site, a Pygmy village. I feel like he was orphaned, or being fostered, and attending a new boarding school, where he didn't fit in well. He's befriended by one unusual boy, who notably collected [*Soldier of Fortune*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldier_of_Fortune_(magazine)) magazines. Toward the end, he gets stabbed in the finger by a "booby trap" of sorts, at the site - a rattlesnake fang, filled with venom.

I read this back in middle school ('85-88), but never have been able to locate the title.

Comment: Do you recall any fantasy or sci-fi elements? Otherwise, this is off-topic here, but fine for the Literature SE.

Comment: @DanBron yes, this is it. If you search the book on Google books [it mentions the Soldier of Fortune magazines](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=sRfIhoOkXygC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=fortune). Are you going to post this as an answer?

Comment: THAT’S IT!! (Exclaimed in best Charlie Brown imitation )

Comment: Thank you so much! My first time here, so thank you for helping me out. Yes, I guess it’s a bit misplaced though I thought the ancient civilization might fit. I will try to list the answer.

Comment: @peaony thanks for confirming that Dan found the correct story. I'll mark this as a duplicate.